# Do prophecies have expiration date after which they would be deemed mistaken?

Tags: theology, nevua-prophecy

Reading some of the Haftoros from Ezekiel (8 or 23), I noticed that some of them had yet come to fulfillment, such as the total desolation of Egypt or Babylon.

How should we treat those prophecies: should we believe it didn't happen YET, or can there be an expiration date that would deem those prophecies mistaken or allegorical?

Comment: Some prophecies contain within them dates, but they can be hard to calculate. For example, the prophecy that the Temple would be rebuilt after 70 years.

Answer (score 2):

The Talmud [Megillah 14a] tells us that the number of prophets was twice the number of Israelites who left Egypt (i.e., 1,200,000). However, only the prophecies of 48 prophets and 7 prophetesses were recorded because their they were relevant for future generations; the prophecies of the others were not.  There is no hint of an "expiration date".  So whatever prophecies were recorded that haven't happened yet will happen in an unspecified future.

Comment: Or *could* happen. Even when God predicts destruction people can repent.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your argument. Are you saying that because a prophecy must be relevant to future generations it therefore can’t have an expiration date? But aren’t there many prophecies that have already been completed, yet are still recorded?

Comment: You can't unrecord them, can you?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi You can't unrecord them, but clearly being relevant for future generations doesn't mean that it can't be fulfilled prior to those generations.